# AWS Certificate manager Renewal-Eligible and CloudFront distribution will it auto renew?

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, ssl-certificate, amazon-cloudfront, aws-certificate-manager

I got an SSL certificate for my domain name from AWS Certificate manager. I have attached the aforementioned certificate to the CloudFront distribution.

The status of the certificate Renewal eligibility is `Eligible`
[image]

Will the certificate be automatically updated in CloudFront around May 23, 2023?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if it's Eligible and if you are using DNS validation it will automatically renew. If instread, you are not using DNS validation, you will recieve communication about taking appropriate action 45 days before expiration.
You can check [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/managed-renewal.html) and [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/acm/latest/userguide/email-validation.html) (in case of email validation) for more information.